# nonexample that pointwise convergence does not implies integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

We have the well-known result that:

> Given a finite measurable set $E$ and a sequence of uniformly integrable functions $f_n$ over $E$, if $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., then $f$ is integrable over $E$.

The idea is: using the finite partition to control the integral since uniformly.

My question is why uniformly integrable is necessary here, is there example that non uniform it may fails?

Comment: Take $f_n = \mathbb{1}_{[1/n,1]}f$ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1]$.

Comment: I get it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given example $f_n = 1_{[1,\frac 1n]} f$ , $f = \frac 1x$ on $(0,1]$ serves as a counterexample.

The reason is that if the $f_n$ are uniformly integrable, then their integrals don't blow up , because you can split your domain into two parts by cutting off $f_n$, one which is controlled by uniform integrability (a "large $f_n$" part) and the other where you control the integral of the $f_n$ because $f_n$ is "small" there. Pushing such an inequality(which holds for all $n$ because of u.i) to the limit $n \to \infty$ gives that any pointwise limit would be integrable. Without uniform integrability, you would not be able to write the inequality at all.